# How do you install nvidia divers if it is not shown in additional drivers and and when installed how to get it to work?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, nvidia-optimus

the output of `sudo lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D'` is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

and after i have installed 390 driver because i searched and found that that is the last version to get supported for my 820m.I have also installed primus and bumblebee as it supports optimus but when I run a program writen in opengl it shows that it is using intel hd graphics. how do i run that in nvidia gpu?

Isn't there any straight forward way of getting nvidia to work even on older cards?

Any links to solution will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please check /etc/modprobe.d/ if there is any filename.blacklist.conf showing your nvidia card name, if yes, then rename it as filename.blaclist.conf.bkp and reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an another way you can follow to install the drivers when it is not shown in additional drivers menu

Note: You need to reinstall the driver if there is an kernel update.

Source of this info: [here](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07)

**Install NVIDIA Graphics Driver via runfile**

Initially remove all the previous Nvidia drivers (Important)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

# Note this might remove your cuda installation as well
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download the required driver from [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)

**Install dependenices**

For Ubuntu, installing the following dependencies is enough.

1. `build-essential` -- For building the driver
2. (Optional) gcc-multilib -- For providing 32-bit support
3. `dkms` -- For providing dkms support

As a summary, All the above packages can be installed using this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib dkms`

**Create Backlist for Nouveau driver**

Create a file at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with the following contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then,

for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, reboot the computer;

for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, excute `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot the computer;

**Stop lightdm/gdm/kdm**

After the computer is rebooted. We need to stop the desktop manager before excuting the runfile to install the driver. `lightdm` is the default desktop manager in Ubuntu. If GNOME or KDE desktop environment is used, installed desktop manager will then be `gdm` or `kdm`.

For Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04, excuting `sudo service lightdm sto`p (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

For Ubuntu 16.04, excuting `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

**Excuting the Runfile**

Enter the tty and enter these commands to execute the file

```
cd ~
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run --dkms -s
```

These errors can be safe to ignore

```
WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib' and X module path '/usr/lib/xorg/modules'; these paths were not queryable from the system.  If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.
```

**Check the Installation**

After a successful installation, `nvidia-smi` command will report all your CUDA-capable devices in the system.

Hope this helps and please upvote if you find useful

Comment: it worked, recommended if you have similar problems..

Comment: @ankit please upvote and accept the answer